# dynamic data driven UI

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I would like to build a webpage of whose the UI would be data driven. As in, the **meta-data** (layout, structure, components, content etc) of the UI would be stored in a database, which would be fetched at realtime, from which the UI will be generated accordingly. Any pointer or suggestions as to how I could go about it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also store the entity data in this database or do you only want to configure the presentation of "static" (strange to use that word here) pages?

If you also store data, you need to make an important decisions about how closely you want to tie the data model with the view model, since your view definitions is also data.

Define tables for Entity, Property and populate them with some example data.

For defining the views, it might be a better option to look for an XML structure that you can store in a database, because page layouts are very hierarchical in nature.

Comment: Well yea I would only want to configure the presentation of the pages. I shall consider XML structure too. <br /> Thanks a lot though.

Comment: If you thought the answer was helpful, please Accept it :-)

Comment: Yup done. I was just waiting to see if there would be other responses. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689097/php-memcache-html-caching)
is probably close to what you are looking for. Just store the HTML code in your database and pull it out with whatever web serivce works best for you. I would also suggest using an associative model of data. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and others like it handle small amounts of complex data more efficiently than a standard SQL database*. They also allow you to read/write to the database from JavaScript. You could possibly develop an administration system for your front end meta using the same technique.